# T-SQL Return Price Based on Tiers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to query what a customer's current price list is for products. Each customer record has up to 3 price codes. Price_code is the first price. If an item isn't on that list or the price is expired then the system looks at Price_code_2, then Price_code_3. To add to this, each customer can have a customer part record that will override all 3 price codes. The query I had worked for the customer part record and the price_code entries, but is ignoring price_code_2 and price_code_3. The customer in the example below has customer part pricing and values for all 3 price codes.

```
declare @Customer as varchar(8)
    , @Today as date

set @Customer = 'tre001'
set @Today = GETDATE()

select distinct SOFCM.CUSTOMER_ID 
    , CUSTOMER_NAME 
    , ICFPM.PART_ID 
    , ICFPM.PART_DESC 
    , ISNULL((case when SOFCP.QUOTE_UNIT_PRIC IS not null then SOFCP.QUOTE_UNIT_PRIC 
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE IS not null then PC1.SO_UNIT_PRICE
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_2 is not null then PC2.SO_UNIT_PRICE 
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_3 is not null then PC3.SO_UNIT_PRICE 
                    end), SOFPL.SO_UNIT_PRICE ) as 'Default_Price'
    , ISNULL((case when SOFCP.QUOTE_UNIT_PRIC IS not null then 'CustPart' 
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE IS not null then PC1.PRICE_CODE 
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_2 is not null then PC2.PRICE_CODE 
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_3 is not null then PC3.PRICE_CODE 
                    end), 'LP' ) as 'Default_Price_Code'

from SOFCM 
cross join (select distinct PART_ID 
                , PART_DESC 
            from ICFPM
            where PART_ID like 'cm-%') ICFPM
left outer join SOFCP 
    on SOFCM.CUSTOMER_ID = SOFCP.CUSTOMER_ID and ICFPM.PART_ID = SOFCP.PART_ID and SOFCP.DATE_LAST_QUOTE <> ''
left outer join SOFPL PC1
    on SOFCM.PRICE_CODE = PC1.PRICE_CODE and ICFPM.PART_ID = PC1.PART_ID and PC1.EFFECTIVE_DATE <= @Today and PC1.END_DATE >= @Today
left outer join SOFPL PC2
    on SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_2  = PC2.PRICE_CODE and ICFPM.PART_ID = PC2.PART_ID and PC2.EFFECTIVE_DATE <= @Today and PC2.END_DATE >= @Today
left outer join SOFPL PC3
    on SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_3  = PC3.PRICE_CODE and ICFPM.PART_ID = PC3.PART_ID and PC3.EFFECTIVE_DATE <= @Today and PC3.END_DATE >= @Today
left outer join SOFPL
    on ICFPM.PART_ID = SOFPL.PART_ID and SOFPL.PRICE_CODE = '12N' and SOFPL.EFFECTIVE_DATE <= @Today and SOFPL.END_DATE >= @Today

where SOFCM.CUSTOMER_ID = @Customer 
    and ISNULL((case when SOFCP.QUOTE_UNIT_PRIC IS not null then SOFCP.QUOTE_UNIT_PRIC 
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE IS not null then PC1.SO_UNIT_PRICE
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_2 is not null then PC2.SO_UNIT_PRICE 
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_3 is not null then PC3.SO_UNIT_PRICE 
                    end), SOFPL.SO_UNIT_PRICE ) is not null
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the nasty `ISNULL` chunk from the `WHERE` clause? Why didn't you just check the various fields for NULL in the `WHERE` clause, e.g. `and ( SOFCP.QUOTE_UNIT_PRIC is not NULL or SOFCM.PRICE_CODE is not NULL or ... )`? Is the `EFFECTIVE_DATE` column `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange design of tables... the query you wrote above means that when the effective period is different, the price code also changes. Anyway, the problem is that
SOFCM.PRICE_CODE, SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_2, SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_3 always returns NOT NULL.
Check PC1.PRICE_CODE, PC2.PRICE_CODE, PC3.PRICE_CODE instead.
Now, you want to evaluate quote_unit_price first?
Maybe it works.

```
select distinct SOFCM.CUSTOMER_ID 
    , CUSTOMER_NAME 
    , ICFPM.PART_ID 
    , ICFPM.PART_DESC 
    /*
    , ISNULL((case when SOFCP.QUOTE_UNIT_PRIC IS not null then SOFCP.QUOTE_UNIT_PRIC 
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE IS not null then PC1.SO_UNIT_PRICE
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_2 is not null then PC2.SO_UNIT_PRICE 
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_3 is not null then PC3.SO_UNIT_PRICE 
                    end), SOFPL.SO_UNIT_PRICE ) as 'Default_Price'
    , ISNULL((case when SOFCP.QUOTE_UNIT_PRIC IS not null then 'CustPart' 
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE IS not null then PC1.PRICE_CODE 
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_2 is not null then PC2.PRICE_CODE 
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_3 is not null then PC3.PRICE_CODE 
                    end), 'LP' ) as 'Default_Price_Code'
    */
    ,case  when PC1.PRICE_CODE is not null then PC1.SO_UNIT_PRICE
           when PC2.PRICE_CODE is not null then PC2.SO_UNIT_PRICE 
           when PC3.PRICE_CODE is not null then PC3.SO_UNIT_PRICE 
    end as 'Default_Price'
    , ISNULL((case  when PC1.PRICE_CODE is not null then PC1.PRICE_CODE 
                    when PC2.PRICE_CODE is not null then PC2.PRICE_CODE 
                    when PC3.PRICE_CODE is not null then PC3.PRICE_CODE 
                    end), 'LP' ) as 'Default_Price_Code'
    , SOFCP.QUOTE_UNIT_PRIC
from SOFCM 
cross join (select distinct PART_ID 
                , PART_DESC 
            from ICFPM
            where PART_ID like 'cm-%') ICFPM
left outer join SOFCP 
    on SOFCM.CUSTOMER_ID = SOFCP.CUSTOMER_ID and ICFPM.PART_ID = SOFCP.PART_ID and SOFCP.DATE_LAST_QUOTE <> ''
left outer join SOFPL PC1
    on SOFCM.PRICE_CODE = PC1.PRICE_CODE and ICFPM.PART_ID = PC1.PART_ID and PC1.EFFECTIVE_DATE <= @Today and PC1.END_DATE >= @Today
left outer join SOFPL PC2
    on SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_2  = PC2.PRICE_CODE and ICFPM.PART_ID = PC2.PART_ID and PC2.EFFECTIVE_DATE <= @Today and PC2.END_DATE >= @Today
left outer join SOFPL PC3
    on SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_3  = PC3.PRICE_CODE and ICFPM.PART_ID = PC3.PART_ID and PC3.EFFECTIVE_DATE <= @Today and PC3.END_DATE >= @Today
left outer join SOFPL
    on ICFPM.PART_ID = SOFPL.PART_ID and SOFPL.PRICE_CODE = '12N' and SOFPL.EFFECTIVE_DATE <= @Today and SOFPL.END_DATE >= @Today

where SOFCM.CUSTOMER_ID = @Customer
    /*
    and ISNULL((case when SOFCP.QUOTE_UNIT_PRIC IS not null then SOFCP.QUOTE_UNIT_PRIC 
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE IS not null then PC1.SO_UNIT_PRICE
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_2 is not null then PC2.SO_UNIT_PRICE 
                    when SOFCM.PRICE_CODE_3 is not null then PC3.SO_UNIT_PRICE 
                    end), SOFPL.SO_UNIT_PRICE ) is not null
    */
    and case  when PC1.PRICE_CODE is not null then PC1.SO_UNIT_PRICE
           when PC2.PRICE_CODE is not null then PC2.SO_UNIT_PRICE 
           when PC3.PRICE_CODE is not null then PC3.SO_UNIT_PRICE 
    end is not null
```

Comment: I was able to use your solution, then create a column that compared the Default_Price with SOFCP.QUOTE_UNIT_PRIC to determine which price to use. Going that route in the beginning would have saved me a lot of time. Thanks for the assist!